# How do I construct a PrivateRoute for a component which relies on a state component 'isAuth' from a (separate) Login class?

Tags: reactjs, routes

I'm fairly new to React, but I've been puzzling over various ways to construct a PrivateRoute all day and haven't been able to figure out how to properly authenticate a user via my login form.

Below is the code for my routing, as well as the Login class and the PrivateRoutes function (contained in a separate file). I suspect that the issue is likely something to do with my lack of understanding regarding props vs. state variables and which can be passed up to parent classes.

Here is the Routing file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Style.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import PublicLanding from './Pages/PublicLanding'
import AllClasses from './Pages/AllClasses'
import Classes from './Pages/Classes'
import Schools from './Pages/Schools'
import Home from './Pages/Home'
import Signup from './Pages/Signup'
import Login from './Pages/Login'
import NotFound from './Pages/NotFound'
import PrivateRoute from './Pages/PrivateRoute'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>

      <Route exact path='/' component={PublicLanding}/>

      <Route exact path='/signup' render={() => (
          <Signup/>
      )}/>

      <Route exact path='/login' render={() => (
          <Login/>
      )}/>

      <Route exact path='/schools' render={() => (
          <Schools/>
      )}/>

      <Route exact path='/classes' render={() => (
          <AllClasses/>
      )}/>

      <Route exact path='/classes/:course_code' render={() => (
          <Classes/>
      )}/>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Home}/>

      //generic path to render if none of the other work
      <Route path='*' render={() => (
        <NotFound/>
      )} />

      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is the Login class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isEmail: false,
      warningText: '',
      invalidReason: '',
      isAuth: false
    };
  }

  login = () => {
    // make sure it's a valid email before checking the database
    if (this.state.isEmail) {
      var details = {
        'email': this.state.email,
        'password': this.state.password
      };

      const formBody = Object.keys(details).map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(details[key])).join('&'); // Putting json into acceptable format to be read
      fetch('http://localhost:8888/authenticate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: formBody
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if(responseJson.page === "Home"){
           this.setState({
             isAuth: true
           });
        } else {
          this.setState({invalidReason: responseJson.error}, () => {
            this.invalidAuthentication();
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      if (this.state.email + this.state.password === '') {
        this.setState({invalidReason: 'You need to enter a username and password'}, () => {
          this.invalidAuthentication();
        });

      } else {
        this.setState({invalidReason: 'Your credentials are incorrect.'}, () => {
          this.invalidAuthentication();
        });
      }
    }
  }

  invalidAuthentication = () => {
    alert(
      this.state.invalidReason,
      [
        {text: 'Ok'},
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  }

  invalidEmail = () => {
    this.setState({
      warningText: "Please enter a valid official school email address."
    })
  }

  verify = (email) => {
    this.setState({
      email:email
    });
    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})/;
    if (reg.test(email) === false){
      this.invalidEmail();
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isEmail: true,
        warningText: ''
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isAuth) return (
      <PrivateRoute to="/dashboard" auth={this.state.isAuth}/>
    );
    return (
      <div className="render-events">
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <label>
          Username:
           <input type="text" placeholder="email@school.edu" onChange={(text) => this.verify(text.target.value)}/>
          </label>
          <label>
          Password:
          <input type="text" securetextentry="true" onChange={(text) => this.setState({password:text.target.value})}/>
         </label>
         <button onClick={() => this.login()}>
         Login
         </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

And finally, here is the PrivateRoutes function:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    (props) => (
      <Route
        render={(props) =>
          props.isAuth === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
      />
    )
)

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I would really appreciate some help with this, as I haven't really found a comprehensive explanation of how to either a) craft a login function within the Routing screen (which seems inefficient) or b) pass the isAuth prop back up to my Routes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not passing the isAuth prop to your privateRoute. Also, why do you want to send it back up?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal Sorry, this might be a dumb question, but where do you mean to pass the prop? In the PrivateRoute function?

Comment: <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Home}/> out here you need to pass the isAuth prop so that it is accessible in the component. Like this  <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" isAuth={isAuth} component={Home}/>

Comment: The issue is that the isAuth={isAuth} yields an error due to the fact that isAuth is a state variable of the Login class, not the Routes class. That's why I was originally asking how to pass a state var up to a parent from a child. Nonetheless, your answer is helpful, thank you for the tip.

Comment: You can loft state to the closest common ancestor (i.e. parent) and pass callbacks to children to use, use a global state object context, or global state management system like redux. The react docs cover the first two cases. Redux uses react contexts under the hood. Then the private route component can access the `isAuth` "state" by either having it passed to it as a prop, or accessing via a context consumer.